# Android - Saving Form Data To A Different Activity

Tags: android, forms, android-activity

I am making an android app and I am having trouble on one aspect of my app. I will explain it clearly as possible.

I have 2 Activities.

FirstActivity = This has a form which allows the user to input information about the subjects they are doing (i.e. subject name, year, course etc). There is also a button called "ADD" which submits the form data every time the form is filled out.

SecondActivity = Once the user submits the form data I want it to display here. I know how to transfer data to this activity. The problem that I am having is, how can I submit more than one "subject" and keep adding it to this activity and saving each entry.

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: save the data to a database or create a class that holds the data and send a list to the activity

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Can you direct me to any information where I can do this. I am new to Android. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add to what @tyczj said. If you want the data to be persistent (meaning it will remain in the app even if the app is killed), you should store it in a database.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html

If you don't need the data to be persistent, you can create another class which both Activities can reference to get the data.